# "non numeric argument" error when testing variable importance

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I've running different models on my dataset but I keep getting the same error when testing out the variable importance:

```
Error in y - mean(y, rm.na = TRUE) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
In mean.default(y, rm.na = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

For example I'm running a knn model with:

```
fit_control <- trainControl(## 10-fold CV
  method = "repeatedcv",
  number = 10,
  repeats = 2,
  classProbs = TRUE,
  verboseIter = TRUE)
```

and

```
knn_noise_fit_big <- train(is_exceed ~ ., 
                       data = trainSet, 
                       method = "knn",
                       # tuneLength = 5,
                       trControl = fit_control)
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO; please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Well, you got the `na.rm` option in the wrong way. Try with `mean(y, na.rm = TRUE)`